# Updating to Drush 7 on OSX

Tags: drush

I had a working drush 5.6 (manually installed) on OSX (Yosemite) and decided I wanted to upgrade to the latest drush 7 version. I ended up with version 6.0-dev.

I followed the installation isntructions and decided to use homebrew to install composer and drush. So far so good, but the thing is, I can't seem to get to the latest "master" dev version: I'm stuck on 6.0-dev.

I tried different ways like:

```
brew install --HEAD drush
brew switch drush HEAD
```

and:

```
composer global require drush/drush:dev-master
composer global update
```

My composer.json looks like this:

```
{
    "require": {
        "drush/drush": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

which drush:

```
/usr/local/bin/drush
```

drush status:

```
 PHP executable        :  /usr/bin/php                             
 PHP configuration     :                                           
 PHP OS                :  Darwin                                   
 Drush version         :  6.0-dev                                  
 Drush configuration   :                                           
 Drush alias files     :  /Users/albert/.drush/aliases.drushrc.php
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Package management always feels a bit unnecessary for Drush, the simplest way to install (in my experience) is `git clone https://github.com/drush-ops/drush.git /usr/local/share/drush; cd /usr/local/share/drush; composer install; ln -s /usr/local/share/drush/drush /usr/local/bin/drush`.

Comment: Oh, and the result of `which drush` is wrong if you've installed via Composer. The correct path would be somewhere in `~/.composer/` (or wherever you have composer install to globally). You've probably installed via brew, that didn't work, haven't _removed_ the brew version, then installed via composer, and forgotten to add composer's global path to your system path. So it's still picking up brew's version in /usr/local/bin. `brew remove drush` before trying the composer method, then add that path to system path, and you should be good

Comment: Thanks, your first approach seems to work like a charm! Still a bit confused what is wrong in my setup. Had probably something do with the old version.. So I deleted /usr/local/bin/drush before creating the new symlink.

Comment: If you have multiple Drush executables in your $PATH, you need to make sure that the one you want to use ($/.composer/vendor/bin) comes first. To do this, set your $PATH in .bashrc somewhere near the top, before the line `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return`. Removing all of the other installations of Drush on the system also works, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You should add to your `~/.bashrc` file the additional PATH, e.g.:

```
# Add a Composer's global bin directory if exists.
which composer >/dev/null && export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

It should come first before your other drush. See my full [.bashrc](https://github.com/kenorb/dotfiles/blob/master/.bashrc) for details (bash4 syntax).

---

Alternatively install `drush` by specifying `COMPOSER_BIN_DIR`, like:

```
COMPOSER_BIN_DIR=/usr/local/bin composer global require drush/drush:dev-master
```

Assuming that `/usr/local/bin` is already in your `PATH`.

Comment: kenorb, your .bashrc has an error. You erroneously changed `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return` to not return; this might cause problems when using this .bashrc in a non-interactive shell. You should put the $PS1 check back the way it was, and then move the code that sets the $PATH, and anything else needed in non-interactive shells, to someplace above this line.

Comment: @greg_1_anderson Thanks, I'll have a look into it and re-test.

Comment: @greg_1_anderson I think it should work fine for bash4, otherwise there is a possible syntax error with older versions. If that's you mean. Otherwise I can't find `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return` code in that file. Which line it's?

Comment: You have the comment line `# Determine within a startup script whether Bash is running interactively or not.` unchanged from the Debian original, but the code that follows you changed to `if [ ! -z "$PS1" ]; then echo ".bashrc loaded." fi`. You should put that back to `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return`, and move only the needed parts (e.g. setting $PATH) above that line.

Comment: @greg_1_anderson Thanks, I did that. I also think to move composer PATH above that condition, otherwise non-composer drush would be used by default when invoking non-interactive commands on remotes.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to Drush 7

- Remove old Drush : brew uninstall drush.
- Install Composer : curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
- Get drush from homebrew : brew install --HEAD drush
- After that command has run, check the drush version :  brew info drush
- If it's still on 6.x (which it shouldn't be), check to the HEAD version by running : brew switch drush HEAD
- Composer Install : cd /usr/local/Cellar/drush/HEAD/libexec && composer install
- Check your work : drush cc drush ; drush --version ;